ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen 1, Ubuntu 23.10 networks show question marks
I have just updated to 23.10 from 22.04.
Wifi connects to my network, but shows question mark icon and no internet connection
The same story with both Ethernet and network through Bluetooth.
nmcli general status

shows:
connected (site only) | Connectivity - 

limited| wifi-hw - enabled | wifi - enabled | wwan - enabled

